# Why should we use <?php for embedding php code?

Tags: php

I once posted a question here with php code embedded using `<?`.
Someone told me I should NOT do that and I should use `<?php`

The person did not tell me why it is so. Can someone please explain why it is unsafe to use `<?`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<?` (the short tags) can be disabled in the PHP configuration, see `short_open_tag`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Why disable it? In some cases you'd want to use `<?xml..` definitions for example, sure there are other ways to output that, but it's just safest to use `<?php` - especially if you plan on moving your code from server to server.